# Selecting main math font in LuaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, luatex, fontspec

I’d to set some fairly simple maths in Minion Pro (and potentially other system fonts), using LuaTeX.  I’d hoped that something like the following should work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}
Here’s some text.  Now some math: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$.
\end{document}
```

However, the `x^2 + y^2 + z^2` is set in Computer Modern.  Material in `\mathit`, `\mathrm` etc. appears in Minion as hoped, and can be further controlled by `\setmathrm` and so on, but is there any way to control the main math font?

I don’t have Minion Math, and trying to use ordinary Minion Pro as the math font via `unicode-math` doesn’t help—indeed, it puts `\mathit` material back into CM!  `MnSymbol` also doesn’t help.  But in any case, I’d prefer a solution that generalises to other fonts, if possible.

Alternatively, changing to XeLaTeX, the `mathspec` package does the trick, using `\setmathfont(Digits,Latin){Minion Pro}`.  But I’d be sad to give up `microtype` and the rest of the power of LuaTeX!

Comment: You don't show how you tried to use Minion Pro with `unicode-math`, so it is hard to tell why it didn't work for you (it should).

Comment: @KhaledHosny: I added the lines `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, `\setmathfont{Minion Pro}` to the preamble; I tried it both before and after the `fontspec` / `\setmainfont` lines.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply setting `\usemathfont{Minion Pro}` with `unicode-math` will not work since it expects an OpenType math font, but you can use `range` option to use normal text fonts for certain math alphabets (or any math symbol), check documentation for details.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{Asana Math} % for math symbols, can be any other OpenType math font
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]  {Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{Minion Pro Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{Minion Pro Bold Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]  {Minion Pro Italic}

\begin{document}
Here’s some text.  Now some math: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, $\mathrm{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}$, $\mathbfit{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}$, $\mathbf{x^2 + y^2 = z^2}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah; marvellous.  This works beautifully.

Comment: In Hosny's solution. `\partial`, `\nabla` will be lost. It seems, that Minion Pro Italic has no corresponding codepoint. Is it possible to take particular glyphs such as  `\partial` and `\nabla` from Asana Math ?

Comment: I think symbol csnames (or code points) can be use as arguments to `range` option, check the manual.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`mathastext`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Here’s some text.  Now some math: $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I tried this, but wasn’t quite sure about it, since `mathastext` also changes several other things about how math is set.  The documentation lists some of these changes and how to turn them off (eg the size of subscripts), but it wasn’t quite clear to me if the listing was exhaustive or if there might be some other changes made as well.

Comment: From what I know it documents all that it does.  But @KhaledHosny's solution is probably a better route to take.