# Modifying EB Garamond font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ebgaramond

Is possible modifying [this](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/downloads) font to have only the "normal" s and u also in the doubles ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[pagesize=auto, version=last]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont[RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+ss05,+dlig},ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+cv04,CharacterVariant=5:2}]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\booktitlefont[LetterSpace=40,WordSpace=2,RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+dlig}]{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\spacedfont[LetterSpace=20,WordSpace=3,RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+dlig}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item pression
\item s
\item u
\item bassun
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the raw font features `+ss02,+cv01` from the font loading commands.  (You may want to remove the other raw features too).

Comment: Thanks ! do you know also why this two command \scshape\lsstyle dont have any effect on the writing? And how i can use this font for the equations ?

Comment: @FormlessCloud Many `microtype` features including `\lsstyle` don't work with XeLaTeX.  For using the font in equations see this question: [Selecting main math font in LuaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34855/2693) (The answers will work for XeLaTeX as well.)

Comment: perfect ! the last things what i must substitute at {Minion Pro Bold Italic}, {Minion Pro Italic}, {Minion Pro Bold} for the EB Garamond font ? At the firs, for examples, "{Minion Pro}" i have substitute "{EB Garamond}"..

Comment: @FormlessCloud Yes. Perhaps you should take a look at the `fontspec` documentation, where the commands you are using are all explained.  You can use `texdoc` to look at package documentation.  See this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63359/2693 for how to use it in Windows.

Comment: Ok thanks ! i have try to put \setmathfont{Latin Modern} but i get: The font "Latin Modern" cannot be found \setmathfont{Latin Modern} this font isn't from default installed?

Comment: @FormlessCloud The names of the fonts are the names of fonts that are installed as regular fonts in your system. (I.e. fonts you could use with any application). Latin Modern is installed as part of your TeX distribution, and needs to be loaded with its filename: `\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}`. See the `unicode-math` documentation for more information.