# Difficulty finding/selecting CM Bright using `fontspec`

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm trying to modify the fonts in my document so that normal text comes up in Calluna, and maths comes up in Computer Modern Bright.

My preamble goes something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{unicode-math}

    \setmainfont{Calluna}
    \setmathfont{Asana Math}  
    %\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{CMU Bright Medium}
    %\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{CMU Bright SemiBold}
    %\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{CMU Bright SemiBold}
    %\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{CMU Bright Medium Oblique}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{cmbright}
\fi
```

I've gotten to this stage after looking at [other examples on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34855/selecting-main-math-font-in-luatex) that appeared to work for other people.

All the `\setmathfont` commands are commented out because they gave me an error "font-not-found". Currently, Asana Math is working (for some reason). Other fonts like Latin Modern Math do not.

Calluna is one of my system fonts and comes up fine.

How should I proceed in order to set the maths font to CM Bright? Also, what exactly does the package `unicode-math` do?

Comment: The most common reason I see an error like this is some simple mistake with the naming of the font, for example typing "BabelUnicode" instead of "BABEL Unicode".

Comment: Since you have a response below that seems to answer your question, please consider it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows that the answer helped you, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect your font files in `Windows Explorer`, you will indeed see that the fonts are called `CMU Bright Medium` and `CMU Bright Medium Oblique`.

[image]

Since `fontspec` can't find those fonts, it means that those names are wrong. If you look at the font name in [FontForge](http://fontforge.org/), for example, you can see that the actual font name of `CMU Bright Medium` is `CMU Bright Roman`.

[image]

I don't know why Windows thinks differently. Now, if you use the real font names, `fontspec` finds them and loads them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathup]{CMU Bright Roman}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{CMU Bright SemiBold}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathbfit]{CMU Bright SemiBold}
    \setmathfont[range=\mathit]{CMU Bright Oblique}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

This solves your problem, which is that `fontspec` couldn't find the `CMU Bright` fonts. Now, you will notice if you compile the `MWE` above that `fontspec` throws a few warnings at you, of the following kind:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "script-not-exist-latn"
* 
* Font 'CMU Bright Roman' does not contain script 'Math'.
* 'Latin' script used instead.
*************************************************
```

These are warnings, not errors. As I understand it, `fontspec` is simply telling you that the fonts you're loading aren't set up for math use. So you shouldn't use them for math as you're doing here.

Comment: I was poking around in the MikTex 2.9 folder on my C: drive (I usw Windows) and the only thing I could find was `CMU Bright Medium`, etc. Could you list what the files are called on your computer as well so that I can check where they are? I'm sure I'll have this problem again and have to poke around, but having a vague idea of where to go would be nice!

Comment: Also, your solution didn't work on my system:  `fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Style=MathScriptScript' (+ssty) not available for font
* 'CMU Bright' with script 'Math' and language 'Default'.`

Comment: @jamesh625 I've updated my answer. The fact that ``fontspec`` gives you a warning means that my solution _did_ work on your system. If it didn't you would get an error.