# TeXworks can't find MinionPro.sty file and subsequent default to TU

Tags: luatex, minionpro

I run the following MWE using LuaLaTeX in TeXworks

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document} 
   \textsc{Hello World.}
\end{document}
```

and it gives an error 
    File `MinionPro.sty` not found.

If I now input the file name with the full path,

> C:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro.sty

it finds the file, but produces an output that isn't in small caps so there seems to be a substitution at work.

The log file says

> Try loading font information for TU+MinionPro-OsF" and "No file TUMinionPro-OsF.fd

which is correct - there are OT1, OT2 fds (among others) but no TU file.

So where should the `.sty` (and Fd) files be put so that TeXworks will find them?  And will the TU issue then resolve itself?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) How did that `MinionPro.sty` get there? My TeXLive 2017 does not include it.

Comment: Do you actually have the MinionPro font? The files from CTAN, does not include the font (as far as I know)

Comment: I went through a partially successful fontinst process that created the .sty file and then I copied the files by hand into TeXworks and added the path (apparently unsuccessfully) using its Preferences.  I copied the fd files from Adobe Acrobat and added a online ones as an experiment.

Comment: (1) did you update the file name database? Searching disk is a costly operation, so latex relies on prebuild lists of file locations. (2) personal stuff should not go into the `texmf-dist` tree, probably better in `texmf-local\tex\latex`

Comment: You can always test whether latex can find a file by using e.g.`kpsewhich MinionPro.sty` in a terminal/dos prompt.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick!!!  I knew how to update it in MiKTeX but had never needed to do it using TeXworks.  I've still got the font substitution issue - back to Googling:-)

Comment: note the issue is unrelated to texworks (which is just the editor so not responsible for finding any files) it is the texlive configuration that you need

Comment: with luatex you do not want to use the minionpro package to load an 8bit T1 encoded subset of the font, use `fontspec` and load the opentype font directly, see the example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34855/selecting-main-math-font-in-luatex

Comment: For once, I prefer my Minion Pro in pdfLaTeX, because `microtype` works there better. If you have the font, have installed the font, and LaTeX now finds the `.sty`, use: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` `\usepackage[fullfamily,footnotefigures,lf]{MinionPro}` `\usepackage[toc,enum,eqno,bib]{tabfigures}` `\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}` `\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}` `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` for more or less full setup. Of course, you can replace the `helvet` and `beramono` fonts with others of your choice. This config uses `latex` in pdf mode, not `luatex`.

Comment: Oh, and the insanely elaborate `microtype` setup for which I am willing to go such lengths is `\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},kerning=true,spacing=true,tracking=true,final]{microtype}` `\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}`. Take care, if you use `ragged2e`...

Comment: That's all very helpful - I've now got a very good looking pdf!  For some reason I don't recall, microtype previously wouldn't allow the kerning option.

Comment: So today I come back to this and there's a new set of errors.  I'm totally lost, and will open a new question based on the new errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using luatex you can use the full Truetype font directly, you do not need to take a 127 (OT1) or 256 (T1) character subset of it as needed for classic TeX, you just need the font to be installed.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Minion Pro}

  \begin{document} 

    \textsc{Hello World.} Hello World.

  \end{document}
```