# MinionPro font installation followup

Tags: luatex, fontspec, minionpro

I posted a question and got some very useful feedback at [TeXworks can't find MinionPro.sty file and subsequent default to TU](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414536/texworks-cant-find-minionpro-sty-file-and-subsequent-default-to-tu#414536)

The MWEs from there no longer seem to be working and I'm posting them both with the errors that are now occurring.  I'm not sure what's changed or what the underlying problem is.

First, David's

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Minion Pro}

  \begin{document} 

    \textsc{Hello World.} Hello World.

  \end{document}
```

Which gives a LuaLaTex error ending in

```
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)(load luc:
          C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl
/lmroman10-bold.luc)(load luc: C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-
cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-italic.luc)))
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); 
reason: "Font MinionPro not found.".
```

And the second from Oleg

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[fullfamily,footnotefigures,lf]{MinionPro} 
\usepackage[toc,enum,eqno,bib]{tabfigures} 
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet} 
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono} 
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

  \begin{document} 

    \textsc{Hello World.} Hello World.

  \end{document}
```

apparently different

```
(./test2.tex
(using cache: C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo(load luc: C:/texlive/2017
/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otl/lmroman10-regular.luc)))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty) 
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/MinionPro.sty
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/MinionPro-FontDef.sty (./otfontdef.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/eufrak.sty)) (./fontaxes.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.522   \DeclareEncodingSubseTS
                             1}{MinionPro-TLF} {1}%
```

Comment: well the first error means that luatex can not find the font, either because you don't have it or it isn't in the font path or... the second error looks like a typo, should that really be capital `TS` at the end?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "no longer working" they were tested just yesterday with texlive 2017. This question appears to be a duplicate of yesterdays unless you have added some new information?

Comment: The second is a cut 'n paste :-(  It looks to me like a parsing error of \DeclareEndoding deep in maybe fontinst.sty.  I thought I'd sorted out the path issues, kpsewhich finds MinionPro.sty in my TEXMFLOCAL.  As recommended, I moved stuff to there from TEXMFHOME, that's probably the main change.

Comment: finding a .sty file is irrelevant to the luatex font loading via fontspec, luaotfload needs to find the font.

Comment: your log shows that the undefined command is in MinionPro.sty (which I don't have)

Comment: it should presumably say `\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{MinionPro-TLF} {1}` but as I say using an 8bit encoding with luatex seems a poor choice to me.

Comment: I included it in the local update.cfg but that file doesn't seem to be available (although I can see it and edit it).  I get

Comment: included what in update.cfg? the main issue (with your first example at least ) is that luatex can not find the font (installing it in windows is the easiest way to fix that)

Comment: Yes, I think there are two separate issues.  The first, as you say, is that the font isn't yet installed.  The second I think came from a corrupt update.config file that I've now fixed.  The relevant part of MinionPro.sty is % fix \r A
  \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\r}{OT1}{A}
     {\leavevmode\setbox\z@\hbox{!}\dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@-1ex%
     \ooalign{\hss\raise.67\dimen@\hbox{\char23}\hss\crcr A}}

  \DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{MinionPro-LF}  {1}%
  \DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{MinionPro-TLF} {1}%
etc

Comment: if you use the version I suggested you don't need the minionpro.sty at all

Comment: I did as you suggested and it's all working nicely now!